# Is there any alternative for the function file_get_contents()?

Tags: php

In my web hosting server, `file_get_contents()` function is disabled. I am looking for an alternative. please help

Comment: Also fread() is disabled

Comment: I need not to read the content of the url. I just need to execute or trigger the url. For that any other function is there??

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, use cURL to open the url. It's exactly what you need.

Comment: With your question you should have provided a list of all disabled functions on your host, because it's likely that many more are disabled if already `file_get_contents` is disabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

file_get_contents() pretty much does the following:

```
$filename = "/usr/local/something.txt";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
```

Since file_get_contents() is disabled, I'm pretty convinced the above won't work either though.

Depending on what you are trying to read, and in my experience hosts disable remote file reading usually, you might have other options. If you are trying to read remote files (over the network, ie http etc.) You could look into the [cURL](http://us.php.net/curl) library functions

Answer (score 3):

You can open the file with `fopen`, get the contents of the file and use them? And maybe cURL is usefull to you? http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Answer (score 3):

A bit of everything.

```
function ff_get($f) {
        if (!file_exists($f)) { return false; }
        $result = @file_get_contents($f);
        if ($result) { return $result; }
        else {
            $handle = @fopen($f, "r");
            $contents = @fread($handle, @filesize($f));
            @fclose($handle);
            if ($contents) { return $contents; }
            else if (!function_exists('curl_init')) { return false; }
            else {
                $ch = @curl_init();
                @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $f);
                @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                $output = @curl_exec($ch);
                @curl_close($ch);
                if ($output) { return $output; }
                else { return false; }}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious reason why `file_get_contents()` is disabled is because it loads the whole file in main memory first. The code from **code_burgar** could pose problems if your hoster has assigned you a very low memory limit.
As a general rule, use `file_get_contents()`(or -replacement) only when you are sure the file to be loaded is small. With [`SplFileObject`](http://www.php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/classSplFileObject.html#_details) you can walk trough a file line-by-line with a convenient interface. Use this in case your file is big.

Comment: I need not to read the content of the url. I just need to execute or trigger the url. For that any other function is there??

Comment: If you only need to trigger the url and you are not interested in the resonse, `get_headers($url)` will be sufficient imho.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5; // set to zero for no timeout
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: will run in php 5.0 or higher

Comment: this is a time saver in my current situation... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to access a file remotely through http:// or ftp://.

In theory, there are alternatives like [fread()](https://www.php.net/fread) and, if all else fails, [fsockopen()](https://www.php.net/fsockopen).
But if the provider is any good at what they do, those will be disabled too.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [**PEAR package Compat**](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Compat). It is like a official replacement of native PHP functions with PHP coded solutions.

```
require_once 'PHP/Compat.php';
PHP_Compat::loadFunction('file_get_contents');
```

Or, if you don't wish to use the class, you can load it manually.

```
require_once 'PHP/Compat/Function/file_put_contents.php';
```

---

- All compat functions are wrapped by `if(!function_exists())` so it is really fail save if your webhoster upgrades the server features later.
- All functions can be used exactly as the same as the native PHP, also the related constants are available!
- [List of all available functions](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-compat.components.php)

Answer (score 0):

If all you are trying to do is trigger a hit on a given url and don't need to read the output you can use curl() provided your web host has it enabled on your server.

The documentation [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) gives an example of calling a url using curl.

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, there's always cURL. There's a good chance it's installed.