# file_get_contents subtitute function or methods?

Tags: php

In one's server, `file_get_contents` is disabled for security reasons. I need to retrieve xml data. So, what is the best thing to do to :

1. Verify that `file_get_contents` is supported by a server ?
2. Is there any subtitute methods of `file_get_contents` ?

Comment: Use another server...  Restrictions like that do little for actually promoting security (as such most of those restrictions have been pulled from future versions of PHP)...

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804262/is-there-any-alternative-for-the-function-file-get-contents

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check whether or not you can use url's in `file_get_contents()` (and the `fopen()` family of functions) by checking the ini directive [`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen):

```
ini_get('allow_url_fopen');
```

You can get around these restrictions by using:

1. [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)
2. [`fsockopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php)

I strongly recommend cURL. `fsockopen()` is a lot dirtier.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=10349521 - this seems to be a releavant topic

I would try to use simply [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and [fread](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) functions.

First approach:

```
$bufferSize = 1024;
$file = fopen($file,'r');
while($cont = fread($file, $bufferSize)){
 $file_content .= $cont;
}
fclose($file);

var_dump($file_content);
```

Second approach:

```
$filename = "/usr/local/something.txt";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: But the OP said the function was disabled, so if `file_get_contents` is disabled, `fopen` may not be...  And the question didn't say anything about URLs at all actually (It's just assumed based on "retrieve xml data").  If `allow_url_fopen` is disabled, then yes @NullUserException, `fopen` won't work either...  But it might still work given the details in the question...

Comment: @NullUserException: I gathered from the question that file_get_contents may be disabled via directive `disable_functions`. You are talking in your answer about URLs but OP didn't say a word about URLs.

Comment: @irc, Marty I guess I misunderstood/misinterpreted the question. I removed the downvote.

Comment: @NullUserException, I don't think any of us understand the question.  It's not really clearly worded, so either (or both) answer could be correct (or both could be wrong).  We're just making assumptions based upon our interpretation of the question...